# angular $resource `user.$update()` is not found

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a click handler that changes the active flag to true. But `user.$update()` is doing a POST not a PUT.

What is the proper (angular) way to update a user object using `$resource`?

```
$scope.setActive = function(user) {
  User.get({ id: user._id }, function(user){
      user.active = true;
      user.$update();
    });
};
```

My express route should be watching for a `PUT`:

```
router.put('/:id', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.update);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the method of the `$update` function to a `PUT` when you're creating the service/factory:

```
angular.module('app.services').factory('User', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/users/:id', { id: '@_id' }, {
    update: {
      method: 'PUT' // this method issues a PUT request
    }
  });
});
```

[Check this link for more info](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/).